# Как протестировать POST контроллер через WebMVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, юнит-тесты, junit

Уже второй день гуглю, но все безуспешно. Помогите, пожалуйста.. Необходимо протестировать метод контроллера EmployeeController. Метод:

```
@PostMapping("/current/update-email")
    public ResponseEntity<String> updateEmail(@RequestBody String email) {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            String emailVerificationPattern = "^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ0-9.-]+$";
            Pattern validEmailPattern = Pattern.compile(emailVerificationPattern);
            boolean isEmailValid = validEmailPattern.matcher(email).matches();

            if (isEmailValid) {
                Employee employee = securityService.getCurrentEmployee();
                employee.setEmail(email);
                employeeService.save(employee);
                return ResponseEntity.ok("Email changed!");
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Email value is invalid");
            }
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Email is empty");
        }
    }
```

Код самого реквеста на фронте:

```
export const updateEmail = (history, email) =>
  fetch(`/hr-rest/employees/current/update-email`, {
    method: "POST",
    ...getCommonJsonRequestProps(),
    body: email,
  })
    .then(response => throwHttpErrors(response, history))
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(users => users || []);
```

Собственно, что я имею сейчас:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(EmployeeController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={MQAutoConfiguration.class, JmsAutoConfiguration.class})
public class EmployeeControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before()
    public void setup()
    {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void updateEmail() throws Exception
    {
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .post("/current/update-email")
            .content(asJsonString(mapper.writeValueAsString("test@test.com")))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.email").exists());
    }

    public static String asJsonString(final Object obj) {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Получаю ошибку:

> EmployeeControllerTest.updateEmail:72 Status expected:<200> but was:<404>

Понимаю, что скорей всего контент описан неверно, но не знаю, как описать правильно.
Буду крайне рад любой помощи, спасибо.

Comment: Возможно неправильный путь указываешь, а возможно какой-то метод выбрасывает exception с 404 статус кодом. Что в логах ответа (при фейле теста который показывают)?

Comment: @NarasuOo `.andExpect(status().isOk())` этот экспект не проходит, т.к ожидается что вернет статус.ок а возвращается 404. Скорей всего неверно заполняю эту строчку `.content(asJsonString("test@gmail.com"))`.

Comment: Вряд ли. Если бы ошибка была в теле запроса, тогда это был бы не 404 статус. А вне теста работает?

Comment: @NarasuOo запрос и обработчик написаны верно и работают полностью корректно. Возможно я в целом не тот путь выбрал для тестирования и стоит как то полностью переписать тест. Но, честно говоря, идей нет.

Comment: Возможно ошибка в том, что в тесте указан не полный путь. По крайней мере он отличается от вашего запроса с фронта, а именно во фронте `/hr-rest/employees/current/update-email`, а в тесте: `/current/update-email`

Comment: @NarasuOo тоже об этом думал, пробовал и полный путь - результат тот же..

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю /hr-rest - корневой контекст. Если да, то не указывайте его, т.е. в тесте путь будет: `/employees/current/update-email`

Comment: @ArtemBerezovski увы, результат тот же, возвращает 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько я понимаю контроллер не был создан при инициализации контекста.

На мой взгляд наиболее правильно будет заменить `@ContextConfiguration(classes={MQAutoConfiguration.class, JmsAutoConfiguration.class})` на `@Import({MQAutoConfiguration.class, JmsAutoConfiguration.class})`

Похожие обсуждения в английской версии:

- [Spring Boot - Test for controller fails with 404 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41548771/spring-boot-test-for-controller-fails-with-404-code)